# Data extraction from table using SQL query

Tags: sql

I am very new to SQL and had a query with which I think you might be able to help me

I am trying to make a list of studies whose official_title (in the studies table) includes the keyword 'fibrillation'

[image: Studies table with the category official_title marked with yellow arrow]

I have been trying to write a code in SQL to get such information but have failed to do so, I used the following code -

SELECT * FROM studies
WHERE official_title ILIKE 'fibrillation'

I would appreciate it if you could spare a few minutes to help me out!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM studies
WHERE official_title LIKE '%fibrillation%'
```

This will work for you. If this is not what you want, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

you can use SQL "like" to check if it contains the string you're looking for

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE columnN LIKE pattern;
```

For more information check this
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp